# jQuerytools overlay with multiple trigger to one overlay element

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

everyone..
I've searched around but haven't found the answer yet. maybe you can help me here...

I have two (HTML) lists, let's call it "animal" and "fruits". each list has some child, and when I click a child element, it will show the overlay element with the name of clicked child. so far I'm able to have overlay for the "animal" list, but for the "fruits" list nothing is happened.

here's the code to make it easier to understand..

**HTML**

```
<ul id="animalList">
    <li id="1" rel="#aniover">tiger</li>
    <li id="2" rel="#aniover">shark</li>
    <li id="3" rel="#aniover">eagle</li>
</ul>
<ul id="fruitList">
    <li id="1" rel="#fruover">mango</li>
    <li id="2" rel="#fruover">orange</li>
    <li id="3" rel="#fruover">banana</li>
</ul>

<div class="modal" id="aniover">
    <h3>Animal Selected!</h3>
    <span id="anisel"></span>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="fruover">
    <h3>Fruit Selected!</h3>
    <span id="frusel"></span>
</div>
```

**Javascript** [I'm using jQuerytools 1.2.7]

```
jQuery('ul#animalList > li').click(function(){
    anname = jQuery(this).html();
    anid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    antext = '['+anid+'] '+anname;
    jQuery('ul#animalList > li[rel]').overlay({
        mask:{color:'#666666',loadSpeed:100,opacity:0.8},
        onBeforeLoad:function(){jQuery('#anisel').html(antext);},
        oneInstance:false
    });
});
jQuery('ul#fruitList > li').click(function(){
    funame = jQuery(this).html();
    fuid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    futext = '['+fuid+'] '+funame;
    jQuery('ul#fruitList > li[rel]').overlay({
        mask:{color:'#666666',loadSpeed:100,opacity:0.8},
        onBeforeLoad:function(){jQuery('#frusel').html(futext);},
        oneInstance:false
    });
});
```

if I click "shark" from the animal list, the overlay works. but when I click "orange", nothing's happened. can somebody help me to figure this out?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it! *sigh*

first of all, I'm sorry I didn't mention before about the second list ("#fruitList") is generated by jQuery script.

the solution is that I'm supposed to include the overlay properties inside the list generation function, NOT outside as I wrote above. here is the illustration for the whole script...

**my previous script:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    createList(function(){ ... }); //list generation function for the fruit list
    jQuery('#animalList li').click(function(){ ... }); //overlay for animal list
    jQuery('#fruitList li').click(function(){ ... }); //overlay for fruit list
});
```

**my working script:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    createFruitList(function(){
        ... //generate the fruit list
        jQuery('#fruitList li').click(function(){ ... }); //overlay for fruit list
    });
    jQuery('#animalList li').click(function(){ ... }); //overlay for animal list
});
```

OK then, that's all.. case closed!

Answer (score 0):

A potential source of errors is that you're using many times the same id for your li elements. You can use another attribute to store the id of your element.

```
<ul id="animalList">
    <li data-id="1" rel="#aniover">tiger</li>
    <li data-id="2" rel="#aniover">shark</li>
    <li data-id="3" rel="#aniover">eagle</li>
</ul>
<ul id="fruitList">
    <li data-id="1" rel="#fruover">mango</li>
    <li data-id="2" rel="#fruover">orange</li>
    <li data-id="3" rel="#fruover">banana</li>
</ul>
```

-

```
jQuery('#animalList li').click(function(){
    anname = jQuery(this).html();
    anid = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
    antext = '['+anid+'] '+anname;
    jQuery('#animalList li[rel]').overlay({
        mask:{color:'#666666',loadSpeed:100,opacity:0.8},
        onBeforeLoad:function(){jQuery('#anisel').html(antext);},
        oneInstance:false
    });
});
jQuery('#fruitList li').click(function(){
    funame = jQuery(this).html();
    fuid = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
    futext = '['+fuid+'] '+funame;
    jQuery('#fruitList li[rel]').overlay({
        mask:{color:'#666666',loadSpeed:100,opacity:0.8},
        onBeforeLoad:function(){jQuery('#frusel').html(futext);},
        oneInstance:false
    });
});
```

I also suggest a more efficient selector for your li : *#fruitList li*

Comment: thanks for the reply, odupont.. I've tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. any other idea? *anyway, thanks for the `data-*` attribute, I'm still new with the HTML5 features*